# Error: Could not resolve field <apex:inputField>

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex, soql

Trying to edit fields displayed in a Visualforce page and am new to coding.  I am getting this (example) error message:

```
Error: Could not resolve field 'Student_Id__c' from <apex:inputField> value binding '{!att.Student_Id__c}' in page AddAttendee
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Original, working page:

```
<apex:page controller="AddAttendee" id="page" showHeader="false">
    <c:CCHeader />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var count = 0;
        function funcA() {
        //debugger;
            if({!!setCount}){return;}
            else{
               for(var a=0;a<=count;a++){
                   var divObj = document.getElementById('page:formId:pageBlockId:pageBlockTableclsAttendees:'+a+':attCont');
                   var child = divObj.children[0];
                   child.style.textDecoration = 'none';
                   child.style.color = 'black';
                   child.removeAttribute('href');
                   child.removeAttribute('onblur');
                   child.removeAttribute('onfocus');
                   child.removeAttribute('onmouseout');
                   child.removeAttribute('onmouseover');

               }
               count++;
            }
       }   

    </script>
    <apex:form id="formId">
        <apex:outputPanel id="errorPanelId">
            <apex:pageMessages />
        </apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:pageBlock id="pageBlockId">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!doSave}" rerender="errorPanelId"  /> 
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancelSave}" rerender="errorPanelId" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:pageBlockSection id="SectionId1" columns="4">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Select Contact: " />
                    <apex:inputField value="{!att.Contact__c}" required="false"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:commandButton value="Add" action="{!AddContact}" oncomplete="funcA();" rerender="pageBlockId,SectionId1,PanelId,pageBlockTableclsAttendees"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:outputPanel id="PanelId" >
                <apex:pageBlockTable id="pageBlockTableclsAttendees" value="{!tempList}" var="att" rendered="{!tempList.size > 0}">
                    <apex:column headerValue="Attendee Name">
                        <apex:outputField StyleClass="AttendeeName" id="attCont" value="{!att.Contact__c}" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Student ID Number">
                        <apex:inputField id="attStudentId" value="{!att.Student_Id__c}" />    
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Gender">
                        <apex:inputField id="attGender" value="{!att.Gender__c}" />   
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Amount Paid">
                        <apex:inputField id="attAmount" value="{!att.Amount_Paid__c}" />
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Edit I wish to make:

```
 <apex:page controller="AddAttendee" id="page" showHeader="false">
        <c:CCHeader />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var count = 0;
            function funcA() {
            //debugger;
                if({!!setCount}){return;}
                else{
                   for(var a=0;a<=count;a++){
                       var divObj = document.getElementById('page:formId:pageBlockId:pageBlockTableclsAttendees:'+a+':attCont');
                       var child = divObj.children[0];
                       child.style.textDecoration = 'none';
                       child.style.color = 'black';
                       child.removeAttribute('href');
                       child.removeAttribute('onblur');
                       child.removeAttribute('onfocus');
                       child.removeAttribute('onmouseout');
                       child.removeAttribute('onmouseover');

                   }
                   count++;
                }
           }   

        </script>
        <apex:form id="formId">
            <apex:outputPanel id="errorPanelId">
                <apex:pageMessages />
            </apex:outputPanel>
            <apex:pageBlock id="pageBlockId">
                <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                    <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!doSave}" rerender="errorPanelId"  /> 
                    <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancelSave}" rerender="errorPanelId" />
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>

                <apex:pageBlockSection id="SectionId1" columns="5">
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Select Contact: " />
                        <apex:inputField value="{!att.Contact__c}" required="false"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                        <apex:commandButton value="Add" action="{!AddContact}" oncomplete="funcA();" rerender="pageBlockId,SectionId1,PanelId,pageBlockTableclsAttendees"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>

                <apex:outputPanel id="PanelId" >
                    <apex:pageBlockTable id="pageBlockTableclsAttendees" value="{!tempList}" var="att" rendered="{!tempList.size > 0}">
                        <apex:column headerValue="Attendee Name">
                            <apex:outputField StyleClass="AttendeeName" id="attCont" value="{!att.Contact__c}" />
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Student ID Number">
                            <apex:inputField id="attStudentId" value="{!att.Student_Id__c}" />    
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Gender">
                            <apex:inputField id="attGender" value="{!att.Gender__c}" />   
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Ethnicity">
                            <apex:inputField id="attEthnicity" value="{!att.Ethnicity__c}" />
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Grade">
                            <apex:inputField id="attGrade" value="{!att.Grade__c}" />
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="School">
                            <apex:inputField id="attSchool" value="{!att.School__c}" />
                        </apex:column>

                    </apex:pageBlockTable>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

Comment: Are you querying for `Student_Id__c` in the query that generates `tempList`? Have you checked that this field is visible to all profiles?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not related to visibility of field. Problem is there is no field named Student_Id__c on Attendee Object or you have misspelled the api name of the field.
Or may be Student_Id__c is its Parent's field. Do let me know if i am not clear.